# Changing Appsettings.Json dynamically using a Patch Request .Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to create a patch request(Web API) to update one section of appsetting.json file dynamically on a server. I am able to do it but my question is will it restart my application pool or what would be the effect if I change my appsetting.json file dynamically. I am using .net core 2.1

Comment: Share us the code which is used to **update one section of appsetting.json file dynamically on a server**? I made a test with the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068279/manually-trigger-ioptionsmonitor-onchange/53077453#53077453), it seems it did not restart the application pool. I suggest you try the code to see wether the pool is restart.

Comment: I implemented the same code in my application. if this code is not restarting the pool then it should not for me too thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there any other issue with thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am able to do it but my question is will it restart my application pool or what would be the effect if I change my appsetting.json file dynamically.**

For this issue, as my test with [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068279/manually-trigger-ioptionsmonitor-onchange/53077453#53077453), it would not restart the application pool. And, it will take effect by chaning from code.