# Manually trigger IOptionsMonitor<>.OnChange

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, settings

In ASP.NET Core 2.1, I use IOptionsMonitor<> and have it set up so I can successfully get events for when I change the appSettings.json file.  So this is working.

What I want to do now is to manually change some values in my options, through code, and have that trigger all my monitors.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For `IOptionsMonitor<Locations>`, it only changes the value in memory and did not save back to `appsettings.json`. For a workaround, you will need to implement your own method to save the changes back to `appsettings.json`.

- define `IWritableOptions` which inherits from `IOptions`

  ```
  public interface IWritableOptions<out T> : IOptions<T> where T : class, new()
  {
       void Update(Action<T> applyChanges);
  }
  ```
- implement your own `WritableOptions`

  ```
  public class WritableOptions<T> : IWritableOptions<T> where T : class, new()
  {
  private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
  private readonly IOptionsMonitor<T> _options;
  private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
  private readonly string _section;
  private readonly string _file;

  public WritableOptions(
      IHostingEnvironment environment,
      IOptionsMonitor<T> options,
      IConfigurationRoot configuration,
      string section,
      string file)
  {
      _environment = environment;
      _options = options;
      _configuration = configuration;
      _section = section;
      _file = file;
  }

  public T Value => _options.CurrentValue;
  public T Get(string name) => _options.Get(name);

  public void Update(Action<T> applyChanges)
  {
      var fileProvider = _environment.ContentRootFileProvider;
      var fileInfo = fileProvider.GetFileInfo(_file);
      var physicalPath = fileInfo.PhysicalPath;

      var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(physicalPath));
      var sectionObject = jObject.TryGetValue(_section, out JToken section) ?
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(section.ToString()) : (Value ?? new T());

      applyChanges(sectionObject);

      jObject[_section] = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sectionObject));
      File.WriteAllText(physicalPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject, Formatting.Indented));
      _configuration.Reload();
  }
  }
  ```
- Configure `IWritableOptions<T>`

  ```
  public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
  {
  public static void ConfigureWritable<T>(
      this IServiceCollection services,
      IConfigurationSection section,
      string file = "appsettings.json") where T : class, new()
  {
      services.Configure<T>(section);
      services.AddTransient<IWritableOptions<T>>(provider =>
      {
          var configuration = (IConfigurationRoot)provider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
          var environment = provider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
          var options = provider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<T>>();
          return new WritableOptions<T>(environment, options, configuration, section.Key, file);
      });
  }
  }
  ```
- Register in `Startup`

  ```
          services.ConfigureWritable<Locations>(Configuration.GetSection("Locations"));
  ```
- Use

  ```
  public class OptionsController : Controller
  {
  private readonly IWritableOptions<Locations> _writableLocations;
  public OptionsController(IWritableOptions<Locations> writableLocations)
  {
      _writableLocations = writableLocations;
  }

  public IActionResult Change(string value)
  {
      _writableLocations.Update(opt => {
          opt.Name = value;
      });
      return Ok("OK");
  }
  }
  ```
- It will fire the `IOptionsMonitor<>.OnChange`

Comment: When u say that " For IOptionsMonitor<Locations>, it only changes the value in memory...." It means that it will behave as a cache value?. How long it will be available for?

Comment: @D.B It will lost when the application restart or recycle.