# Where to store Access and Refresh tokens when consuming external APIs using IHttpClientFactory. Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, token, refresh-token, httpclientfactory

I am using IHttpClientFactory for sending requests and receiving HTTP responses from my Web API to an external APIs using Net Core 2.2.

The access token and the refresh tokens used to send the request to the API have been stored in the appsettings.json. When a request returns 403 or 401 errors, I get a new token dynamically and add it to the header of the request.

But How Can I update appsettings.json  with the new access and refresh token in order to use it for subsequent requests.

Is It there a much better approach to store access and refresh tokens than the appsettings.json?

Comment: I presume you are using `Auth Flow` when getting the access token. Can you please share ConfigureServices code in the Startup file? In general you can store the token in cookies. Storing in appsettings.json is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `IHttpClinetFactory` (and assuming you are using [Typed Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-httpclientfactory) as well), you can create your own [HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#outgoing-request-middleware) which would be triggered before any request made by your `Typed Client` and link it with your `typed client` via DI like this:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IServiceContract, ServiceImplementation>()
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenHandler>();
```

Inside that `TokenHandler` you can check if the request has a token in the headers or not. If not check the cache (Memory Cache) for available tokens, then validate the lifetime of the token.

If the token is expired or there is no such a token in the cache, issue a new one and store it in the cache.

I am sure there are better ways, but that what I would do.

---

**Note:** If your application is distributed on multiple servers, then use [Distributed Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead of the [Memory Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2). You can add either easily via DI.

---

**Update:**

You can register your handler like this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<TokenHandler>();
```

Comment: Hey I know this is a year old but I'm trying to do the same thing in terms of refreshing a token supplied with a header. I created a class TokenHandler that implements Delegating Handler and chained it onto my typed HttpClient like in the example above. If you could help me, I'm wondering how the TokenHandler needs to be registered because I'm getting a 'No service for type TokenHandler has been registered' error. If you could help me with this I would highly appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for not putting the registration sample, you can register the `handler` as transient `services.AddTransient<TokenHandler>()`.

Answer (score 3):

Giving the hypothesis your client WEB API connects automatically to your external APIs (and also, ask automatically the tokens), you don't need to store tokens and refresh tokens.

Your webservice needs to keep the tokens in memory (in a singleton) and use it whenever needed.

When the external API wants a new token (e.g. after token expiratoin), you just need to ask a new one and update your singleton.

We use this way of working for several projects and it's reliable.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. When a request is sent to my AP,I the WebAPi controller is created right, then when the response is sent to the client the controller is destroyed, which means that the token that was in memory is not available anymore, right?. It means that for every subsequent request i will need to request a new token? . I was trying to store the token I just got with the previous request in the appsettings.json so the new requests can use it.

Comment: You need to store your token as singleton.  it's not destroyed when your controller gets destroyed but when your applicaiton shutdowns (then token is owned by your program)

Comment: Could you please shows an example how it would be to store the token as singleton.

Comment: This could be a recipe for disaster if you're not implementing proper locks on this singleton.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should store the token in database for permanent save by EF Core or any other data provider.

If you insist on saving in the `appsettings.json`, you need to implement the custom feature.

For a demo, check [Manually trigger IOptionsMonitor<>.OnChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068279/manually-trigger-ioptionsmonitor-onchange/53077453#53077453)

Comment: Thanks. I will consider your suggestion. And the link provided is great.